# Convert DateTime with a specified language

Tags: datetime, asp.net-mvc-5, utc, cultureinfo, localtime

I am coding a MVC 5 internet application and am wanting to convert a `DateTime` to be displayed as a `LocalTime` where I have the language. This is for an `Azure` website.

Here is my code:

```
DateTime dateTimeUtcNow = DateTime.UtcNow;
DateTime convertedDate = DateTime.SpecifyKind(dateTimeUtcNow, DateTimeKind.Utc);
DateTime dateTimeLocalTime = convertedDate.ToLocalTime();
return dateTimeLocalTime.ToString(new CultureInfo("en-NZ"));
```

The output from the above code is the exact same output as if I return the `DateTime` in `UTC` with no language culture specified.

How can I convert a `DateTime` in `UTC` for a local time where I have the culture language?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the second argument to the `toString` function and use any language/culture you need...

You can use the `"d"` format instead of `ToShortDateString` according to MSDN...

So basically something like this to return as NewZ ealand English:

```
CultureInfo enAU = new CultureInfo("en-NZ");
dt.ToString("d", enAU);
```

you could modify your method to include the language and culture as a parameter

```
public static string ConvertDateTimeToDate(string dateTimeString, String langCulture) {

    CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo(langCulture);
    DateTime dt = DateTime.MinValue;

    if (DateTime.TryParse(dateTimeString, out dt))
    {
        return dt.ToString("d",culture);
    }
    return dateTimeString;
  }
```

You may also want [to look at the overloaded](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9h21f14e.aspx) `tryParse` method if you need to parse the string against a particular language/culture...